# Trying to generate custom JSON with anonymous types

Tags: c#, json, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I've recently been learning how to generate `json` and `geojson` streams from datatables. It's been an uphill battle to say the least.

Currently I'm trying to create a custom `JSON` stream for a chart. This is the correct `JSON` format:

```
{
    "labels": ["January","February","March","April"],
    "datasets": 
    [{
        "label": "NAME",
        "data": [1,2,3,4]
    },{
        "label": "NUM",
        "data": [11,12,13,14]
    }]
}
```

My datatable looks like this:

```
monthname   Data1   Data2
January     1       11
February    2       12
March       3       13
April       4       14
```

So far this is what I have:

```
public static string DataTableToCustomJSONString(DataTable dataTable)
{

    string monthName = string.Empty;
    string data1 = string.Empty;
    string data2 = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        monthName += row["MonthName"].ToString() + ",";
        data1 += row["data1"].ToString() + ",";
        data2 += row["data2"].ToString() + ",";
    }
    monthName = monthName.Remove(monthName.Length - 1);
    data1 = data1.Remove(data1.Length - 1);
    data2 = data2.Remove(data2.Length - 1);

    var obj = new
    {
        labels = monthName,
        datasets = new dynamic [] {
        new { label = "NAME", Data = data1 }
        ,
        new { label = "NUM", Data = data2 },
    }
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);

}
```

Which returns the following json:

```
{
  "labels": "January,February,March,April",
  "datasets": [
    {
      "label": "NAME",
      "data": "1,2,3,4"
    },
    {
      "label": "NUM",
      "data": "11,12,13,14"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the months should be enclosed by brackets and each month has double-quotes (`["January","February","March","April"]` instead of `"January,February,March,April"`).

Also, the `data` property should look like this `[2,3,4,5]`, but instead is enclosed by *double-quotes* (`"11,12,13,14"``).

Also, I'm not sure if iterating through the datatable is the best way to generate the months string.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
monthName += row["MonthName"].ToString() + ",";
```

You are telling it to concatenate the value into one long string with commas in between. So that's exactly what it's doing for you.

If you want it to be an array, you can use a `List<string>` and add each value. They will be serialized into a JSON array:

```
var months = new List<string>();
var data1 = new List<string>();
var data2 = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    months.Add(row["MonthName"].ToString());
    data1.Add(row["data1"].ToString());
    data2.Add(row["data2"].ToString());
}
```

Then you also don't need those lines that remove the last comma.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was one long string. I just didn't know how to include an array.